# Draw line between two points on console

Tags: java, algorithm, dda

How can I draw a line on the console if I have a 2D array of chars. The function I want to write is something like:

This is my first attempt, but it looks totally wrong

```
public static void line(char[][] mPixels, int startRow, int startColumn, int endRow, int endColumn) 
{
    double dY = endRow - startRow;
    double dX = endColumn - startColumn;
    double slope = dX / dY;
    slope = Math.abs(slope);

    if(slope >= 1)
    {
        double progress = -(dY / dX);
        for(int i=startColumn; i<=endColumn; i++)
        {
            double j = startRow - (int) ((i-startColumn) * progress);
            int yLoc = (int) (Math.round( j * 100.0 ) / 100.0);

            mPixels[i][yLoc] = '*'; 
        }
    }

// print array  
}
```

Comment: May I suggest this awesome tool called google. Just search for it and find the wiki article.

Comment: should add a rasterize, line ,DDA tag and delete those for loops tag they are not relevant for search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **DDA** or **Bresenham**,...

What you have looks like **DDA** but you do not handle slopes correctly. You should divide by the axis with bigger amount of pixels and use it as control axis so:

if `|dx|>|dy|` then `for` goes through `x = x0 -> x1` and  `y=y0+((x-x0)*dy/dx)`

if `|dx|<|dy|` then `for` goes through `y = y0 -> y1` and  `x=x0+((y-y0)*dx/dy)`

if they are equal then use any of above.

if `dx==0` and `dy==0` draw just dot and no `for` is present

Do not forget to handle if main axis is ascending or descending (can be `x++,y++` or `x--,y--`) also can be done on integer only without division or multiplication but that is another story